# Updated this morning lost monitor

Tags: monitor

Updated 12.04 this morning and lost monitor with VGA connection. Using laptop for this email.

Have tried to reinstall from CD 4 times now but still nothing. Older tower has SUSE on it can't even see that. Love Ubuntu but good grief. Help please.

Have found some information on what to put in the `sudo` but can't see anything how do I get back?

Also planning on upgrading video card so can run HDMI to big screen any suggestions on that?

Comment: Maybe is only a X mis configuration. Which is your video card? Can you attach your X config file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working... Took it apart checked the connections inside (had cleaned it when first took apart). Unplugged the hard drive plugged it back in added power and wala working. got two error messages (did not wright them down) then stared up with my original settings of ubuntu. Not sure what the problems were and being a nob does not help. : ). I learned a lot.. Thanks for the input. – Lana 2 days ago

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to install ubuntu from [the alternate cd](http://mirror.bytemark.co.uk/ubuntu-releases/precise/ubuntu-12.04.1-alternate-amd64.iso)
2. Boot from Live CD and update your additional drivers then your system `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: Did that nothing.. Even made a new download disk and tried that still nothing. Took apart computer did cleaning.. Unplugged monitor (VGA flat screen) to reset. Still nothing. When turned on says no signal and is only on for maybe 2 minutes before it shuts off.  Tried to hook lap top to it but that did not work either.. to the point of just picking up a new tower and starting over... LOL

Comment: Ok got it downloading alternate now will give it a try. Thanks

Comment: Did not work. : (